# How to copy manually only a single site package without pip install?

Tags: python, pip, site-packages

First, my reasons to do this - I know it's a bad idea but I am out of ideas.

I want to install a package which requires a `ld` version, which is higher than the one in the repo of my Centos 6.5. So I should either go for setting up everything in a Docker and running it in production - something I lack experience with and I don't feel comfortable doing for a serious project. Or upgrade `ld` manually building from external source. Which I read, could result in devastation of my Centos. So the last option I am left with is install the packed on other machine and manually copy it to `site-packages`.

I have successfully installed the package on my home laptop under Debian.

I encountered everywhere advice to copy the whole `site-packages` directory. Something which I don't want to do as I have different packages on both machines and I want to avoid messing up with other stuff.

I copied the `.so` build and `.egginfo` of the package. Then, on the target machine, `pip freeze` indeed showed me the transferred package. However, Python can't find it when I try to import and use it.

Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not any of that.**

Don't mess with system Python's site-packages dir, this belongs to the system Python env only. You should only add/remove code in there by using the package manager of your OS (that's `yum` for CentOS). This is especially true in Linux where many OS services can rely on system Python.

So what to do instead? Use a virtualenv and/or [pipx](https://github.com/pipxproject/pipx) to isolate any other dependencies of the package you want to install from the system versions.

Comment: Do you mean to create a virtualenv on the Debian where I can install the package, install all other packages I need in it, and copy the entire virutalenv folder on the target Centos server, then run my app using the virtualenv?

Comment: First let me clarify, is the only thing that you need a newer version of ld (The GNU linker) to *install* the Python package from source? If that's the case, I think you should just `altinstall` a newer linker (or just prepend one in PATH temporarily) and build a Python bdist for this package.

Comment: It seems so, I was told its version is too old by the package dev, the package itself has no other pip dependencies. On my Debian it installed immediately.

Comment: I don't want to install any linker out of the repo as I don't want to take any risk. I read the consequences can be dramatic and this is a production server.

Comment: You don't have to install it. Just prepend a newer linker from your homedir on the PATH temporarily, or use an environment module.  Then do `python setup.py bdist_wheel` to build a bdist file which you can use going forward, without needing a linker at install time anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with this stuff. No idea where to get a newer version which to prepend, etc... I guess your idea for virtualnv is good so I am accepting your answer. Thank you for your time.